# remove double quotes from specific part in python

Tags: python, json

```
import json,re

text = '{"restName":"apple","restaurantTotal":150,"vouchers":null}'
obj = json.loads(text)
print(obj)
if 'banana' not in obj['restName'] and obj['restaurantTotal'] <= 200:
    obj['vouchers'] = '[{"Discount":'+ str(obj['restaurantTotal']/2) +'}]'
result = json.dumps(obj ,separators=(',', ':')).replace("\\","")
print(result)
```

Result

```
{"restName":"apple","restaurantTotal":150,"vouchers":"[{"Discount":75.0}]"}
```

I want to remove the double quotes from this part only `(")[{"Discount":75.0}](")` any way to do it ?

Comment: *You* assigned a string to `obj['vouchers']`, rather than an actual list containing a dictionary.  Assign `[{"Discount": obj["restaurantTotal"]/2}]` instead, rather than doing unnecessary string building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t write the value as a string. `json.dumps` will handle that.

```
obj['vouchers'] = [{"Discount": obj['restaurantTotal'] / 2}]
result = json.dumps(obj)
```